# Why request payload is empty when using useState to set in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

I have an async function inside useEffect to fetch data based on given input from database(mongodb)using Express.js.
On submitting the form it should pass the state(inputs given) into server and find data then return the result back to front end.
But while submitting it send empty state and returning empty array.

[Rsponse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ah5n.png)
[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moWqZ.png)

React Component:Compare.js
`

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Result from "./Result";

export default function () {
  const [compare, setCompare] = useState({
    proId1: "",
    proId2: "",
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    setCompare((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  }



  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/compare", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        proId1: compare.proId1,
        proId2: compare.proId2,
      }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    return data
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>ENTER IDS TO COMPARE</h1>
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="proId1"
            placeholder="proId1"
            name="proId1"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={compare.proId1}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            className="proId2"
            placeholder="proId2"
            name="proId2"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={compare.proId2}
          />

          <button
            className="submit"
            onClick={
              React.useEffect(() => {
                fetchData()
              },[fetchData])
            }
          >
            SUBMIT
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Result />
    </>
  );
}
```

`
server:

`

```
app.post("/api/compare", async  (req, res) => {
  try {
     let id1 = await req.body.proId1;
    let id2 = await req.body.proId2;
    let result = await model.find({ id: { $in: [id1, id2] } })
    res.send(result)
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ status: "error", error: "error" });
  }
});
```

`
expected Request:

`

```
{
    "proId1":"1",
    "proId2":"3"

}
```

`expected Response`

```
[
    {
        "_id": "637c5dddb9b084433f13d3f7",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "dffdf",
        "price": "100$",
        "ratings": "2",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "637c5df3b9b084433f13d3fb",
        "id": "3",
        "name": "dffdf",
        "price": "25$",
        "ratings": "5",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

`

Comment: Have you checked, that the state is set correctly, before starting the request?

Comment: yes, I'm setting the 'compare' state whenever the value in the input box changes.

Comment: So, if you `console.log(compare.proId1, compare.proId2)` inside the `useCallback` before `const response`, it shows the correct values?

Comment: NO,it is also empty .why its not setting the 'compare'?

Comment: Dude, quick fix  =>  onClick={  fetchData }, useCallback dependency  array [compare.proId1, compare.proId2], check new React docs https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects, the will help overall, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your hooks incorrectly.

I recommend you read [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) gently and pay attention on useCallback and useEffect.

```
            onClick={
              React.useEffect(() => {
                fetchData()
              },[fetchData])
            }
```

this is not the way to use **useEffect**.

**onClick** you want to load your data so do

```
onClick={fetchData}
```

Also **useCallback** without dependencies is also seamless, it is memoization hook that holds income values to avoid bouncing. So you can put your state into its dependency, but it seems to me a bit excessive and you can use it without useCallback wrapper.

inside of your ***fetchData*** handler you want to put the result into the state to display it later, so define state for the result and set it inside the handler

```
  const [apiResponse, setApiResponse] = useState();

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/compare", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        proId1: compare.proId1,
        proId2: compare.proId2,
      }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    setApiResponse(data)
  }, [compare]);
```

and put somewhere in your render return

```
apiResponse.map(({ id, name }) => (<div key={id}>{name}</div>))
```

Comment: i fixed it with above code,but when i hit submit button it just console for a second and then disappear immediately...on Network tab its not showing any status..

Comment: But did you display it somewhere in the code? State will not show on the screen if you will not put it somewhere in your code. where do you wanna show it?

Comment: i want to display the 'apiResponse' in the child compenet .i tried to pass the 'apiResponse' as a prop into child and console from there,but it showing(on console) an empty array

Comment: Thank you bro...i got it.passing 'event' to the async function and then using event.preventDefault() will fix the issue of console disappearing.....thank you so mush for your help as i am new to coding and React